# 'ComputedObject (Error) User memory limit exceeded' when exporting small extracts of unaltered Landsat 8 scenes to ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

I am trying to export a small area (a circle 4.2km across) of every Landsat 8 scene within two date ranges (corresponding to 'before' and 'after' the construction of a solar farm).

I have created appropriate ImageCollection Assets, but get the error **ComputedObject (Error) User memory limit exceeded** when I run the code.

I understand the reason for this (or at least I think I do) having read the [Debugging guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging) however the suggested workarounds aren't appropriate as I don't want to process the images in any way (so using a Reducer and increasing the tilesize isn't an option).

All I need is an ImageCollection of unaltered, unprocessed images.

I started with the 'before' collection (about 66 scenes), and given that the 'after' collection is just over 200 I need an approach that will scale.

How should I do this?

```
var Stateline_pre = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
                  .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-09-30');

var Stateline_post = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
                  .filterDate('2016-08-01', '2021-09-20');
                  
//Change vizParams depending on whether mapping L5 or L8 data
var vizParamsL8 = {bands:['B4','B3','B2'],min:0, max:20000,gamma:0.5};
var vizParamsL5 = {bands:['B3','B2','B1'],min:0,max:120};
var vizParams = vizParamsL8;

///////////////CHANGE/////////////////
////Set site name for export to drive
var site = "Stateline";

////////////////CHANGE/////////////////
////Set collection name for export
var collection_name = "stateline_pre_construction_all";

////Automatically select solar park coordinate
//var coordinate = Desert_point;
var coordinate = ee.FeatureCollection('.../'+site+'_point');

////Set centre of map and zoom level
Map.centerObject(coordinate, 12);

////Convert collection to list to allow image export using loop
var list = Stateline_pre.toList(Stateline_pre.size());

//// Selects geometry solar park centre coordinate
//// Need to do this to allow buffer to be created
var solar_coordinate = coordinate.geometry();

//// Create polygon for area to export using buffer function
//// Change buffer area if needed
var extent = solar_coordinate.buffer(2200);
Map.addLayer(extent, {}, 'export_extent');

// Print scene_center_time for each image in collection list
for (var i=0; i<100; i++){
  var image = ee.Image(list.get(i));
  var time = image.get('SCENE_CENTER_TIME');
print(time);}

//// OPTIONAL: Loop to display images on map
//for (var i=0; i<1;i++){
//  var image = ee.Image(list.get(i));
//  var month = image.get('MONTH').getInfo();
  ///Use 'SPACECRAFT_ID' to automatically select correct visual parameters for image (i.e. L5 or L8)
//  var landsat = image.get('SPACECRAFT_ID');
//  if(ee.String(landsat).getInfo()==='LANDSAT_5'){
//    var vizParams = vizParamsL5;
//  }
//  else{
//    var vizParams = vizParamsL8;
//  }
//  Map.addLayer(image, vizParams, month,false);
//}

//// Export each image to image collection in Assets
for (var j=0; j<100; j++){
var image = ee.Image(list.get(j));
//// Use date to identify the image
var id = image.get('DATE_ACQUIRED').getInfo();
  Export.image.toAsset({
    image: image,
    description: id,
    assetId: ".../"+ collection_name+"/"+id,
   scale: 30,
  region: extent  
  });
}
/*
//// Export each image to google drive
for (var i=0; i<12;i++){
var image = ee.Image(list.get(i));
var image = image.select(['B1','B2','B3','B4']);
//// Use date to identify the image
  var id = image.get('DATE_ACQUIRED').getInfo();
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: collection_name+ 'Landsat_'+ id,
    folder: site,
    scale: 30,
  region: extent  
  });
}
*/
//print(collection);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugging guide you've already referenced (and the best practices page right next to it) says, pretty explicitly:

1. Don't use for loops.
2. [Don't use getInfo](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging#browser-lock).
3. [Don't convert collections to lists.](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid-converting-to-list-unnecessarily)

so clearly, they do apply to your code.

Your main problem is that you haven't spatially filtered the collection, so there's actually  212,000 images in your first collection (which you unnecessarily convert into a list) and 769,000 images in the second (which you also convert into a list).  Just fixing that will make your script run, even with the remaining bad practices.

But the better way to do this is to use getInfo **ONCE** to get the list of IDs and/or dates of the images (every call to getInfo is another ~2 second wait while your browser is hung).  Then loop over those and filter the collection for each Export.

```
var ids = Stateline_pre
  .filterBounds(extent)
  .map(function(img) {
    return img.set('export_metadata', [img.get('system:index'), img.get('DATE_ACQUIRED')])
  })
  .aggregate_array('export_metadata')
  .getInfo()

// Export each image to image collection in Assets
for (var j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
  var current = ids[j];
  var id = current[0];
  var date = current[1];

  Export.image.toAsset({
    image: Stateline_pre.filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", id)),
    description: date,
    assetId: ".../"+ collection_name+"/"+id,
    scale: 30,
    region: extent  
  });
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/503d3f9697b6c9f5963d07415c183d96

But, all that said, why are you exporting tiny pieces of unmodified images into more assets? Those won't be accessible any better/faster than the original assets (and without exercising more care in the Export, you're actually resampling the inputs).

Comment: Thank you, Noel.  I'm new to Javascript, coding, and Earth engine, so your synthesis of what's going on is really helpful.  I've found the debugging guide (and much of the documentation) is difficult to understand without a certain level of comprehension, which is difficult to acquire because the documentation assumes comprehension...  For instance, I know that you should map rather than loop, but actually implementing that is difficult for a beginner.

Comment: I omitted to spatially filter the collection in error - the existing approach requires me to manually find images which I do using Earth Explorer filtering by path/row, but I'm trying to get more scenes to generate a more accurate average value.  The 'tiny pieces of unmodified images' are to facilitate download (slow connection) and processing locally in GIS (slow computer). Since posting this question it's become apparent the best way forward is to use a reducer in EE and then download a single processed scene of the mean values of the filtered scenes.  I think.

Comment: It would be handy in the documentation if there were more examples to demonstrate how the syntax is implemented.  At least for those of us learning the basics.